# bind/unbind window events in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, window.location

I need to represent window.location.hash by model instance to control its state by events from other models. Also hash can be changed by user manually by typing in adress string. User changes have to translate inside application and application can also modify hash in respond to user interactions with UI they represetns.
Does anybody know how how to update window hash in this case?

```
Hash = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        other_source.on('change', this.setHash, this);
        window.on('hashchange', this.update);//user may update hash manually in browser
        //window.on('hashchange', $.proxy(this.update, this)); - I tried this
        //_.bind(this.update, this); - and this
        // it doesn't work
    },
    update: function(data){
        //translate changes inside app
        this.clear();
        this.set(hashToObj(data));
        this.trigger('hash:changed', this.attributes);
    },
    setHash: function(){
        //Apply changes from inside app
        //I need to temporarily remove listening
        //because of inifinitive loop
        window.off('hashchange', this.update);
        window.location.hash = this.attributes;
        window.on('hashchange', this.update);
    }
})
```

Comment: Why not use [`Backbone.Router`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) and [`Backbone.history`](http://backbonejs.org/#History)?

Comment: Because it is not applicable in my case. I'm developing filter tool similar as [market.yandex.ru](http://market.yandex.ru/guru.xml?CMD=-RR=9,0,0,0-PF=1801946~EQ~sel~1871375-VIS=8070-CAT_ID=432460-EXC=1-PG=10&hid=91013) panel on right side(sorry for russian, donno international analog). Maybe  you have any idea how to apply history and router here? I will be gratefull.

Comment: `window.location.hash` changes are just route changes. The router lets you change routes and respond to route changes.

Comment: But routing means some 'routes'. How can I build routes from 50 or more grouped checkbox values?

Comment: Perhaps a [splat route](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes) would help.